# How to acces all data after filtering and grouping in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have these datarows that I get from server, and looks something like this:

CurrentDate//// Engineer////  LineNumber////  RepairDate 
23-6-2016------------1---------------1------------23-6-2016 
23-6-2016------------1---------------2------------23-6-2016 
 
23-6-2016------------1---------------3------------22-6-2016 
23-6-2016------------1---------------2------------20-6-2016 
23-6-2016------------2---------------7------------23-6-2016 
23-6-2016------------2---------------3------------19-6-2016 
23-6-2016------------2---------------2------------17-6-2016 
23-6-2016------------5---------------8------------23-6-2016 
23-6-2016------------5---------------1------------18-6-2016

Now, what I want to achieve, is, grouping by engineer, and then show the line numbers that were repaired on the current date, those numbers should also be grouped, and show the history of repairs that it had, and the engineer that repaired it on that date.

And should look something like this:

Current Date: 23-6-2016 
Enginner
1
Lines Repaired on Current date:
-1 
Repaired by Eng.5 on 18-6-2016
-2
Repaired by Eng.1 on 20-6-2016
Repaired by Eng.5 on 18-6-2016
Repaired by Eng.2 on 17-6-2016

Enginner
2
Lines Repaired on Current date:
-7 

Enginner
5
Lines Repaired on Current date:
-8


For what I see, I have two problems, first, by grouping, I lose all the engineers data in the details section that Im not currently grouping at the time of printing, and, in the other hand, if I filter rows with a group formula to get only the data with the current date, then I lose all the other dates in the details section as well...

What I have tried is filtering in a header group, just the rows with the current date, but that filters the other rows, and I cant get to atach the history of the LineNumbers., same happens if I group by Engineer... Im pretty new in this And I cant seem to get around with a solution...

Comment: Where did you write your filtering formula?

Comment: I wrote it in the group formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches but the cleanest way is to join the LinesRepaired table to itself on linenumber. I've attached the raw SQL to do this.  You could also skip the SQL and do it in Crystal following the steps below:

1. Left Join the table to itself on L.linenumber = L_1.linenumber
2. Filter where L.repairdate = L.CurrentDate (consider making currentdate a Crystal parameter)
3. Group by L.engineer then by L.linenumber
4. Add L_1.Engineer and L_1.repairdate to Details
5. Suppress details if L.engineer = L_1.engineer AND L.repairdate = L_1.repairdate (because this is the current repair it should not be shown in the history)

   ```
   create table LinesRepaired (CurrentDate varchar(10), Engineer int, LineNumber int, RepairDate varchar(10))
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',1,1,'23-6-2016') 
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',1,2,'23-6-2016') 
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',1,3,'22-6-2016') 
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',1,2,'20-6-2016') 
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',2,7,'23-6-2016') 
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',2,3,'19-6-2016') 
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',2,2,'17-6-2016') 
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',5,8,'23-6-2016') 
   insert into LinesRepaired Values('23-6-2016',5,1,'18-6-2016') 

   select  *
   from    LinesRepaired l
           left join LinesRepaired l2 on l.linenumber = l2.LineNumber and convert(varchar,l.engineer)+'-'+l.RepairDate <> convert(varchar,l2.engineer)+'-'+l2.RepairDate
   where   l.RepairDate = '23-6-2016'
   order by 2,3
   ```

Comment: Thats what I was just looking for, Its been quite a while since I dont work with sql querys, and I have passed the fact that you can join a table to itself. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this, not by Crystal Reports tough, but programmatically, by using applications and identities... such as this:

Head
CurrentDate//// Engineer//// LineNumber//// RepairDate /// DateAPL /// EngineerAPL/// 
 
23-6-2016------------1---------------2------------23-6-2016----23-6-2016---------1-----   >>The identity<<
And their respective applications: 
23-6-2016------------1---------------2------------23-6-2016----20-6-2016---------1-----
23-6-2016------------1---------------2------------23-6-2016----18-6-2016---------5-----
23-6-2016------------1---------------2------------23-6-2016----17-6-2016---------2-----

And so, when I start grouping on crystal reports, I don't lose Key information. Then I just have to group by Date->Engineer->LineNumber, and in the details section, it will show all the Repairs made to that Line.

In the code section, I play with the datatables that I got from database (Im currently using vbnet)

-Filter all engineers in the datarows: 
For each Engineer

-Filter all engineer rows with currentdate

For each Row of current dates

For each row in all data that is not filtered
if currentEngineerLineNumber = alldata.LineNumber and alldata.date <> currentDate 
Add a Row with application data (Engineer and date) to a brand new table 
else
Is the identity, add a row with the identity to that brand new table.